# Add and remove items from list in other class in C#

Tags: c#, list

I am setting up a basic shopping cart in C# using forms. I have loaded a few product into the List<> that can be shown when opened up, but my problem is that when I add or remove an item from the List<> and exit to menu and open shop again the original list is shown. I not sure how to add or remove it from shop that it show up in the original list as well? Thanks for any help.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private List<Product> products = null;

    public List<Product> GetStock()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        products.Add(new Product("D001", "Milk", "Dairy", 1.20m, 10, 1.027m));
        products.Add(new Product("D002", "Cheese", "Dairy", 2.80m, 20, 0.300m));
        products.Add(new Product("F001", "Apple", "Fruit", 0.50m, 10, 0.136m));
        products.Add(new Product("F002", "Orange", "Fruit", 0.80m, 20, 0.145m));
        products.Add(new Product("V001", "Tomato", "Veg", 2.50m, 15, 0.110m));
        products.Add(new Product("V002", "Onion", "Veg", 1.50m, 10, 0.105m));
        products.Add(new Product("M001", "Lamb", "Meat", 4.50m, 10, 0.340m));
        products.Add(new Product("M002", "Chicken", "Meat", 3.50m, 10, 0.907m));

        return products;
    }
```

}

```
public partial class frmAdminMenu : Form
{

    Product products = new Product();
    List<Product> tmpProducts = (new frmMain()).GetStock();


    private void btnAdminAddStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product tmp = new Product(txtCode.Text, txtDescription.Text, category, Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text));
        if (tmp != null)
            tmpProducts.Add(tmp);

        loadProducts();

    }

    private void frmAdminMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string heading = "Code:\tDescription:\tCategory:\tPrice:\tStock:\tWeight:\n";
        lstViewStock.Text = heading.ToString();

        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts()
    {
        lstViewStock.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Product p in tmpProducts)
        {
            lstViewStock.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText("\t"));
        }
    }

    private void btnAdminRemoveStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmpProducts.RemoveAt(lstViewStock.SelectedIndex);

        //tmpProducts.RemoveAt(lstViewStock.SelectedItems);
        loadProducts();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Is `frmMain` always open before `frmAdminMenu`?

Comment: Yes frmMain is the first form that is opened

Comment: The `products` in `GetStock` hides the `products` in `frmMain` -- is that intentional?

Comment: @AustinSalonen I'm thinking not; and yet...

Comment: No it was just some code I found that let me view the products in different classes

Answer (score 0):

When you do this,

```
List<Product> tmpProducts = (new frmMain()).GetStock();
```

You are reinitializing the list back to the original list returned by `GetStock` in `frmMain`. That's the reason it shows you the same list when you open up a new `frmAdminMenu`.

You should try keeping the list as part of a `model` object, and saving it (to the database, file system, memory) when you close the form so the changes are saved, otherwise, the form is not really doing anything.

Comment: What would be the best way of calling the original list at the start but still be able to add or remove from it?

Comment: _reinitializing the list back to the original list in frmMain_ -- not quite.  It's back to the list created/defined in `GetStock` there is a subtle difference here.

Comment: True... and definitely subtle. Changed.